# Flutter: Cropped Shadows on ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I just wanted to create a horizontal ListView in Flutter with some BoxShadows to recreate a 'neomorphism' effect.

I then realized that the shadows on the ListView Items are cropped at the edges. I already tried to adjust all kind of different paddings and margins but the problem persisted.

The weird thing is: Cards that were the Image Assets couldn't be loaded render the Shadow perfectly fine.

[image: ListView Shadow Cropped]

```
class _DrinkListState extends State<DrinkList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: this.widget.availableDrinks.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: LimitedBox(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Container(
                                child: Image.asset("assets/" +
                                    this
                                        .widget
                                        .availableDrinks[index]
                                        .imageName),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child:
                                Text(this.widget.availableDrinks[index].label))
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  decoration: neodec,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 200,
                )),
        height: 300);
  }
}
```

My BoxDecoration:

```
BoxDecoration neodec = BoxDecoration(
    color: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 246, 1),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, offset: Offset(10, 10), blurRadius: 10),
      BoxShadow(color: Colors.white, offset: Offset(-10, -10), blurRadius: 10)
    ],
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)));
```

Comment: The only way to fix it is by adding more padding between your elements... that's it.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Thanks for your answer! So you mean to increase the padding attribute in the ListViewBuilder (currently set to 30?). I already tried that and it didnt help :/.

Comment: You need to increase the padding inside your Container "card" shaped container. I'll recommend to use padding EdgeInsets.symmetric and increment only your width padding and not your height padding. Or if you think only the right padding is the conflicted one, use EdgeInsets.only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to work around the issue by using a Card instead of Center widget in my WidgetBuilder/Container.